# The const keyword in JavaScript:

Tags: javascript, global-variables, constants

Today (in 2014) is it advisable to use the *const* keyword to declare constants in JavaScript? Are there still browser compatibility issues? Also, is there a way to declare a global constant?

Note: This questions is not a duplicate, I am asking for the year 2014. Other posts in Stack Overflow date back to 2008-2012

Comment: Yes, there are still compatibility issues with older browsers. Please specify the targetted browser/engine versions if you need more detailed information.

Comment: The `const` keyword, introduced with JavaScript 1.7 and still apparent in current Firefox, does behave different from the `const` keyword that is envisioned by EcmaScript harmony.

Comment: There are only compatibility issues if there's a browser you support that isn't compatible. Only you can know if it's compatible for your purposes.

Comment: ES6 `const` browser compatibility: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#const

Comment: Whoever voted to close for "primarily opinion based" ... browser compatibility is not an opinion.

Comment: I would strongly advise against it; you should be writing JavaScript in strict mode, which explicitly disallows `const`. If it works, odds are you’re doing something wrong. ES6 won’t be safe for widespread use for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at June 2014, MDN says this:

> The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension
>   and is not part of ECMAScript 5. It is supported in Firefox & Chrome
>   (V8). As of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable
>   with const in these browsers, you can still change its value later. It
>   is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-10, but is included in
>   Internet Explorer 11. The const keyword currently declares the
>   constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).
>
> Firefox, at least since version 13, throws a TypeError if you
>   redeclare a constant. None of the major browsers produce any notices
>   or errors if you assign another value to a constant. The return value
>   of such an operation is that of the new value assigned, but the
>   reassignment is unsuccessful only in Firefox and Chrome (at least
>   since version 20).
>
> const is going to be defined by ECMAScript 6, but with different
>   semantics. Similar to variables declared with the let statement,
>   constants declared with const will be block-scoped.

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Answer (score 1):

`const` was introduced in JavaScript 1.5, was a Mozilla-specific extension and not part of ECMAScript 5.

However, the ES6 draft introduces a different `const`. Similar to variables declared with the `let` statement, constants declared with `const` will be block-scoped.

So basically:

- Some browsers implement the old non standard way.
- Other browsers allow variables declared with `const` to change its value later.
- Other browsers don't implement it at all.
- Currently no browser (AFAIK) implements the ES6 way.

See [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: Which I think leads to the conclusion that unless you're writing code that is only going to execute against one specific JS engine (like running in node.js), you pretty much can't use `const` now because the behavior is variable and going to change in the future.